# In what order are Netty handlers called?

Tags: java, networking, asynchronous, netty

I am new to Netty and a little confused about ChannelPipelines. The concept looks rather elegant, but I am struggling with two points:

1. How is the order of handler calls defined?
2. How does the framework handle upstream sends to a encoder? or downstream sends to an decoder? Do they just get passed along? Can they even occur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The handlers are called like this:

upstream => from the first to the last

downstream => from the last to the first

2) upstream is never passed to an encoder and downstream never to a decoder

Comment: Thanks for that. So should my 'business logic' generally be the final handler in the list?